# How to run a script embedded in the page in Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, embedded-resource, execute

I'm testing a page with [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) and want to execute a method already in the page.  I've tried `getEval(window.name.space.function())` but it just returns `window.name` is undefined.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a getCurrentWindow() function which for unfathomable reasons only allows you to access "safe" properties (what is this supposed to protect against? people maliciously doing drive-by testing of other people's website?). Newer versions offer a getUserWindow() function that solves those issues. See [this blog entry](http://crschmidt.net/blog/348/selenium-ide-getcurrentwindow-problems/) and [this issue](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-558) for details.